# How to pass multiple parameter to --detect.maven.build.command for blackduck hub scanning of maven project using jenkins

Tags: powershell, maven, jenkins

I am passing below command as PowerShell in Jenkins:

`powershell "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'tls12'; irm https://detect.synopsys.com/detect.ps1?$(Get-Random) | iex; detect" --blackduck.url=$env:HUB_URL --blackduck.trust.cert=true --blackduck.api.token=$env:BLACKDUCK_HUB_TOKEN --detect.project.name=$env:HUB_PROJECT_NAME --detect.project.version.name=$env:VERSION --detect.maven.include.plugins=true --detect.included.detector.types=maven --detect.maven.build.command=`"E:\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\mvn.cmd -f pom.xml -s settings.xml -gs settings.xml clean install -DIafConfigSuffix=Cert"`

[image]

but when detect executed, --detect.maven.build.command only pass 1st command as highlighted below:

```
> "C:\Users\a900565\AppData\Local\Temp/synopsys-detect-6.5.0.jar"
> "--blackduck.url=https://blackduckhub.deere.com"
> "--blackduck.trust.cert=true" "--blackduck.api.token=********"
> "--detect.project.name=**********"
> "--detect.project.version.name=master"
> "--detect.maven.include.plugins=true"
> "--detect.included.detector.types=maven"
> "--detect.maven.build.command=E:\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\mvn.cmd" "-f"
> "pom.xml" "-s" "settings.xml" "-gs" "settings.xml" "clean" "install"
> "-DIafConfigSuffix=Cert"  07:58:14 Java Source:
> JAVA_HOME/bin/java=C:\Program Files\Amazon
> Corretto\jdk1.8.0_202/bin/java 07:58:15 ______     _            _
> 07:58:15 |  _  \   | |          | | 07:58:15 | | | |___| |_ ___  ___|
> |_ 07:58:15 | | | / _ \ __/ _ \/ __| __| 07:58:15 | |/ /  __/ ||  __/
> (__| |_ 07:58:15 |___/ \___|\__\___|\___|\__| 07:58:15  07:58:17 
> 07:58:17 Detect Version: 6.5.0 07:58:17  07:58:17 2020-09-11 07:58:17
> INFO  [main] ---  07:58:17 2020-09-11 07:58:17 INFO  [main] ---
> Current property values: 07:58:17 2020-09-11 07:58:17 INFO  [main] ---
> --property = value [notes] 07:58:18 2020-09-11 07:58:17 INFO  [main] --- ------------------------------------------------------------ 07:58:18 2020-09-11 07:58:17 INFO  [main] --- blackduck.api.token =
> **************************************************************************************************** [cmd]  07:58:18 2020-09-11 07:58:17 INFO  [main] ---
> blackduck.trust.cert = true [cmd]  07:58:18 2020-09-11 07:58:17 INFO 
> [main] --- blackduck.url = ************* [cmd]  07:58:18 2020-09-11
> 07:58:17 INFO  [main] --- detect.included.detector.types = maven [cmd]
> 07:58:18 2020-09-11 07:58:17 INFO  [main] ---
> **detect.maven.build.command = E:\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\mvn.cmd [cmd]**  07:58:18 2020-09-11 07:58:17 INFO  [main] ---
> detect.maven.include.plugins = true [cmd]  07:58:18 2020-09-11
> 07:58:17 INFO  [main] --- detect.project.name = ********* [cmd] 
> 07:58:18 2020-09-11 07:58:17 INFO  [main] ---
> detect.project.version.name = master [cmd]
```

How can i pass multiple parameter to detect.maven.build.command?

Comment: Can you please post the powershell command as you would enter it in powershell.  I can format it correctly to be called from jenkins, but it would be easier if you could post the command as it is ran directly in the powershell terminal

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The issue is related to your nested quotation characters and lack of escape characters.  I've taken your PowerShell command and formatted the string correctly with the appropriate escape characters.

```
powershell label: '', script: '''
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = \'tls12\'; 
    irm https://detect.synopsys.com/detect.ps1?$(Get-Random) | iex; 
    detect 
        --blackduck.url=$env:HUB_URL 
        --blackduck.trust.cert=true 
        --blackduck.api.token=$env:BLACKDUCK_HUB_TOKEN 
        --detect.project.name=$env:HUB_PROJECT_NAME 
        --detect.project.version.name=$env:VERSION 
        --detect.maven.include.plugins=true 
        --detect.included.detector.types=maven
        --detect.maven.build.command="E:\\apache-maven-3.0.3\\bin\\mvn.cmd -f pom.xml -s settings.xml -gs settings.xml clean install -DIafConfigSuffix=Cert"
'''
```

## Pipeline Syntax Generator

You can auto generate this script by using the *pipeline syntax* generator in Jenkins.  Configure a pipeline and click the pipeline syntax hyperlink at the bottom.  See image below.

[image: Pipeline Syntax Hyperlink]

From there you can enter the PowerShell script and click **Generate Pipeline Script**

[image]

## Post Script

> I noticed that your PowerShell script has some seemingly misplaced quotation marks.  If my script doesn't run, please post the PowerShell script that you run directly from the PowerShell console and I will update my answer

Comment: used shell script u mentioned bt while running through jenkins it give label error. i removed label and ran script, job was successful but script doesn't execute: I'm running script using jenkins Windows PowerShell and below command 
`--detect.maven.build.command="-f AeaAuthoringWeb/pom.xml -s AeaAuthoringWeb/settings.xml -gs AeaAuthoringWeb/settings.xml clean install -DIafConfigSuffix="Cert" -DIafMOD="aeaauthoringweb" -Dspring.profiles.active="Local""` only return `--- detect.maven.build.command = -f [cmd] ` in jenkins. And if i add \" -f ...\" gives **string is missing the terminator: "**

Comment: Can you please post the entire powershell script that runs successfully within powershell

Comment: `powershell "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'tls12'; irm https://detect.synopsys.com/detect.ps1?$(Get-Random) | iex; detect" --blackduck.url=$env:HUB_URL --blackduck.trust.cert=true --blackduck.api.token=$env:BLACKDUCK_HUB_TOKEN --detect.project.name=$env:HUB_PROJECT_NAME --detect.project.version.name=$env:VERSION --detect.maven.include.plugins=true --detect.included.detector.types=maven --detect.maven.build.command="E:\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\mvn.cmd -f pom.xml -s settings.xml -gs settings.xml clean install -DIafConfigSuffix=Cert"` This powershell command run successfully

Comment: but `--detect.maven.build.command=` only return 1st word in jenkins **detect.maven.build.command = E:\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin\mvn.cmd [cmd]** as sown in log above in question

Comment: Again - its an issue with your nested quotation marks and lack of escape characters. Please post the powershell command *AS IT WOULD RUN IN POWERSHELL TERMINAL* (not the powershell command in Jenkins).  From there I can format it.

Comment: Hi Chris, i am not using POWERSHELL TERMINAL for execution only relying on Jenkins Window Powershell to pass command to run.

Comment: Lalit, I understand this.  I'm asking you to run your command command into the terminal, and post that.  I will then turn it into a jenkins command.  This tells me you know that it runs correctly in powershell first

Answer (score 0):

See quoting and escaping info [here](https://synopsys.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/INTDOCS/pages/631406802/Quoting+and+Escaping+Shell+Script+Arguments#Running-the-PowerShell-script-(detect.ps1)-on-Windows)

So, seeing detect is only grabbing the first "word" of your maven command, consider putting a backtick ` before each of the spaces (and maybe some other special characters) in your maven command.

Other useful options, though maybe not useful here:

```
-hv
--logging.level.com.synopsys.integration=TRACE
```